# How to Create a Simple If Else Statement in Eclipse, PhoneGap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

How will I create a simple onClick() if else statement. that when the user hits the backbutton it will lead to the previouse page or activity in android? below is my code but i know there something missing. and can you please help me out? I am using eclipse with phonegap for Android.

Here is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onBackKeyDown() {
/* WHAT SHOULD I PUT IN HERE? any suggestions?*/
}
</script>
```

Many thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: if else statement to put where?

Comment: in the function onBackKeyDown () {
for me to make a condition that when the user taps on the back button it will take the client to his/her previous activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have registered a listener which will listen to the BackKey of Android.
Now Suppose you want to navigate to a page then you just need to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function onBackKeyDown() {
navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/something.html"); //to go to a page
}
</script>
```

Is this what you want to go to a Page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but i was thinking something like when the user hits the back button it will go to previouse activity. not with the specific page. Thank you :)

Comment: But if you use phonegap then it converts to a webview and you can navigate through url. Dont you have an  activity that you have written through the native code?